# Difference running python in PyCharm and in terminal

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, imagemagick, pycharm, wand

I'm wondering what is the difference when I run a python program from PyCharm or from the command line.

Actually I'm using a library called wand-py (ImageMagick binding).

If I run my program from the command line it works.

Though if I use PyCharm Run or debug it doesn't and I get the following traceback.

```
/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/env/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58993 --file /Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/tets.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 135.973)
pydev debugger: process 73166 is connecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1733, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1226, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/tets.py", line 23, in <module>
    blob = image_to_blob(PATH)
  File "/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/tets.py", line 12, in image_to_blob
    pdf.alpha_channel = False
  File "/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 419, in wrapped
    result = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 992, in alpha_channel
    self.raise_exception()
  File "/Users/alexisbenoist/Documents/python/papyrus/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 218, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-1' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickSetImageAlphaChannel/9504
```

I'm using the same virtual env in the terminal and PyCharm.

Do you guys know what could cause the problem?

Thanks,

Alexis.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I imagine the difference your experiencing is related to paths & working directory configurations in PyCharm IDE. [See docs for config options](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-python.html).

Comment: I think there is a difference from running in PyCharm. I had an experience were the imports worked in PyCharm and not in the terminal. I think that the current directory changes also.

Comment: Did you find any solution?