# Wand ImageMagick will not convert PDF to PNG in Eclipse, works in Terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, imagemagick, pydev, wand

I have a very strange issue. I am trying to use the Wand ImageMagick binding for Python to convert a PDF to a PNG. I am running on Mac, installed ImageMagick with homebrew, and I have installed ghostscript and freetype, which are required for PDFs. I have the following code:

```
from wand.image import Image

img = Image(filename='/users/joelclark/Downloads/test.pdf')

img.save(filename='/users/joelclark/Downloads/test.png')
```

When I run this in Terminal using my python interpreter, it works great, the PNG file is generated. However if I run this same code in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joelclark/Development/lims/mirage/test.py", line 11, in <module>
   img.save(filename='/users/joelclark/Downloads/test.png')
  File "/Users/joelclark/Development/lims/mirage-flask/flask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2719, in save
    self.raise_exception()
  File "/Users/joelclark/Development/lims/mirage-flask/flask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images `MagickWand-1' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickWriteImage/13115
```

Keep in mind that I am using the EXACT same interpreter in Eclipse that I am in Terminal. I have also verified that the Python environments are the same, environment variables are the same, etc. It seems like an issue with Eclipse, but I honestly just cannot tell. I have also tried modifying permissions with chmod. When I did this the number after 'MagickWand' in the stack trace would change. For example 'MagickWand-5' instead of 'MagickWand-1'. I have no idea what this could mean but I figured I should mention it. I read a similar post here [Difference running python in PyCharm and in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484440/difference-running-python-in-pycharm-and-in-terminal) but this was with PyCharm and not Eclipse. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is any more information I can provide please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. My PATH in environment variable was not the same in Eclipse. It was missing the /usr/local/bin path.